# Visualizar imagens no banco de dados com arquivo separado do cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou usando o phpcake como administrador de uma galeria de fotos, as imagens sao salvas dentro da pasta webroot/img/galerias/ para cada categoria é criada uma pasta seguindo uma numeração. Ate ai tudo esta funcionando.

O problema é quando vou listar as imagens em um arquivo fora do phpcake só usando php puro, utilizo o seguinte codigo para chamar as imagens

```
<?php
    $photos = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE galeria_id = $album_id");
        while($photo_data = $photos->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
<img class="img-responsive" src=admin/webroot/img/galerias/"<?php echo $photo_data['galeria_id'] ?><?php echo $photo_data['image'] ?>" />
        </div>
    <?php }
    ?>
```

Depois disso ele me retorna um erro no console do Chrome 403 (Forbidden) o no caminho da foto ele acrescenta `%222bb1d11f-ea8a-4a27-b6f8-f28b1e5098ea.jpg%22`
esses `%222` no inicio e no fim da imagem. Eu só queria colocar o id que é igual ao numero da pasta e depois o caminho que esta salvo em imagem.

Comment: Consegui resolver

Answer (score 0):

Coloca as aspas duplas no começo do caminho da imagem:

```
src="admin/webroot/img/galerias/`<?php echo $photo_data['galeria_id'] ?><?php echo $photo_data['image']` ?>"
```

E certifique-se que este é mesmo o endereço da imagem, pois tenho quase certeza que falta uma barra (/) entre os códigos *php*, e também tenho quase certeza que está faltando ou sobrando algo no começo do caminho...